# querydef doesnt work in exportxml

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a query that i wan't to use in Application.ExportXML. But the query expects a parameter, this parameter has to be a value of textbox in my form. Right now i have something like this.

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE Reports.Ref_Q ='" & txtRef & "';"
    Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("getReports")
    qd.sql = sql
    Application.ExportXML acExportQuery, getReports, strPath
```

When I run this code i get the following error:

```
The command or action '|' isn't avaible now
```

I als tried doing it like this

```
Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("getReports")
qd.Parameters("prm") = txtRef.Value
```

But then the prompt screen for the parameter keeps comming on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("getReports")` is expecting to find a saved query called `getReports`, which may not exist.

You would need something like:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE Reports.Ref_Q ='" & txtRef & "';"
Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("getReports", sql)
DB.QueryDefs.Refresh
Application.ExportXML acExportQuery, getReports, strPath
```

Or:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE Reports.Ref_Q = [prm];"
Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("getReports", sql)
qd.Parameters("[prm]") = txtRef.Value
DB.QueryDefs.Refresh
Application.ExportXML acExportQuery, getReports, strPath
```

`DB.QueryDefs.Refresh` is usually necessary, as without it, Access won't find your newly created query.

Using parameters is preferable when you need to reuse the query lots of times with different parameters, as creating a query has more overhead than just calling it with a different parameter.

You might want to add a `DB.QueryDefs.Delete "getReports"` if you don't want your query hanging around.